# Should I use CharacterSet or URLQueryItem?

Tags: ios, swift, url, nsurlrequest

I have some problem when try to call a url string request with some special character inside. For example with CharacterSet, when in URL have the `%20` that mean spacebar and I use the `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)` function it's replaced to `%2520`. Can you guys try this code:

```
    let url = "http://analytics.abc.io/acct?start_date=2017-11-15&aff=ABC%20Telecom"
    url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
    print(URL(string: url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)!)
```

Actually it's request sucessfully but the response data is wrong. Any guys can give me some ideas and how to solve that clearly.

Beside that please give me some comment about the URLQueryItem I not use that, so I need your help. Thank and cheer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly, is it 100% much better if you decompose using URLComponents. It will facilitate the work for you and the next dev to read the code.

```
let host = "analytics.abc.io"
let scheme = "http"
let path = "/acct"
var urlQueryItems : [URLQueryItem] = []
for (key, value) in [("start_date", "2017-11-15"), ("aff", "ABC Telecom")] {
    urlQueryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value))
}

var result = URLComponents()
result.host = host
result.scheme = scheme
result.path = path
result.queryItems = urlQueryItems

print(result.url)
//prints : Optional(http://analytics.abc.io/acct?start_date=2017-11-15&aff=ABC%20Telecom)
```

Comment: Thanks @CZ54. Your help be very clear and solve my problem now. Coz my reputaion low than 15 so I can't vote for you. Once time thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please Change Your Line with Below

```
(url.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlUserAllowed))!
```

Hope it Helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and i solve using followint trick

```
let url = "http://analytics.abc.io/acct?start_date=2017-11-15&aff=ABC%20Telecom"
    if url.contains(" ") {
            url = urlSTR.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
        }
```

sometimes we get url already encoded from server then it creates some problem.so the best solution will be to ask your server guy to provide url without encoding and manage it from app end.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Don't force unwrap anything, use `if..let` or `guard`

```
let url = "http://analytics.abc.io/acct?start_date=2017-11-15&aff=ABC%20Telecom"

if let finalURL = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) {
    //Do your stuff
}
```